# Why is there no pgpool-II in 18.04 LTS?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a reason why 18.04 has no pgpool-II package available?
packages.ubuntu.com lists 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, and 18.10 but is missing 18.04 LTS.
I did not find a suitable answer to that via popular search engines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pgpool2/+publishinghistory):

> Deleted on 2018-04-02 by Matthias Klose
>   remove pgpool2, autopkg test failures with java9, no rdeps

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of this publishing history.

Comment: In case, how can we install manually in ubuntu 18 server !